# php auto commit or begin transaction are not working as expected

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I am trying to test the php mysqli autocommit function. I have a very basic example below. 
When I run this script the query executes and is inserted in the db. Why does this happen, I have commented out the commit portion and therefore would not expect the query to insert into the db.

```
$db_con=mysqli_connect($server, $dbuname, $dbpassw, $database);
mysqli_autocommit($db_con,FALSE);

mysqli_begin_transaction($db_con);
$sql="INSERT INTO table (a, b, c) VALUES ";
$sql=$sql."('1','2','3')"; 
mysqli_query($db_con,$sql);
//mysqli_commit($mysqli);
```

Thanks

Comment: Tip: A lot of problems can be detected and resolved by [enabling exceptions in `mysqli`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14578243/turning-query-errors-to-exceptions-in-mysqli) so errors resulting from simple mistakes made aren’t easily ignored. Without exceptions you must pay close attention to return values, many of these indicate problems you must resolve or report to the user. Exceptions allow for more sophisticated flow control as they can “bubble up” to other parts of your code where it’s more convenient to handle them.

Comment: thanks I enable it now, no exceptions

Comment: Did you try rolling back explicitly?

Comment: I tried now and it still does the insert

Comment: What type of table do you use? Innodb or myisam?

Comment: I think thats the issue thanks, the tables myisam and db is innodb

Comment: Yeah, MyISAM doesn't support transactions, it just pretends it does. It's also not worth using for a multitude of important reasons, so be sure everything is InnoDB.